# Different symbols when deploying change sets

Tags: deployment, change-set

Does any one know if there is any significance of these different symbols when deploying change sets:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think different symbols are to differentiate deployment. When we deploy components which does not need test class to run then it shows different symbol other than component requires to run test class.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the ui to me. When deploying directly through the metadata api, you don't get those improper fractions, and you get a solid green circle on success.

Comment: Always makes me feel special when I can deploy more components than there  are in the change set. I hope they don't fix this specific issue!

Comment: Its nothing more than a bug where UI and API stop liking each other (Sync issue). These type of symbols don't have any description anywhere in SFDC ux. I have seen 2 others as well.

Comment: This normally happens when we have profiles as part of the deployment process. I believe this is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually several reports of different people catching the "deployment fish", I believe it has to do with the [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T52MAAS), where the -- Component count is reported greater than actual count on deployment status UI page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the main deployment just counts the objects in the top part. When you add in profiles, you get the fish.